# loadUserByUsername with additional parameters in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have implemented custom authentication provider (based on [Custom Password Authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html)) and the thing is that loadUserByUsername (email) method accepts only one parameter. I need one extra there to check if this user belongs to the company ID (taken from the url parameter), because the client can be registered to multiple companies with one email address.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `loadUserByUsername` is implementation of method declared in `UserProviderInterface` you can't change list of arguments, because php will throw error in such case. I see two possible solutions:

1. (bit hackish) In your implementation of `loadUserByUsername` pass array containing `username` AND `ID` you need to check. This is bit hackish because it uses fact that php is not strongly typed and you can pass array instead of string (username) to `loadUserByUsername` method.

   ```
   public function loadUserByUsername($params)
   {
       $id = $params['id']; 
       $username = $params['username']; 
       //now do whatever you need to do with $id and $username
   }
   ```
2. Write your own `loadUserByParams` method which will take array (of `username` and `ID`) and in first step will check if `ID` is ok, if so, it will call regular `loadUserByUsername` method with just `username` parameters

   ```
   public function loadUserByParams($id, $username)
   {
       //check if $id is ok;
       if ($id_is_ok) {
           return $this->loadUserByUsername($username);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but what in case of refreshUser() method? This method still needs to call loadUserByUsername and I don't really know how to pass additional arguments there as well

Comment: ``refreshUser`` accepts one argument of ``UserInterface`` type. You can (and should) write your own implementation of ``refreshUser`` method and call ``loadUserByParams`` inside - so, answering your comment: ``refreshUser`` method does not need to call ``loadUserByUsername`` method

Comment: Everything sounds okay but still I don't know where to call refreshUser method since it's called somewhere internally I suppose.

Since I can do whatever I want with loadUserByUsername within authenticateToken() method of SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface, I still don't know how to call refreshUser (as you said I can call loadUserByParams() inside that method)

Comment: don't worry where to call ``refreshUser`` - as you wrote it is called somewhere internally. Instead, write your own ``refreshUser`` implementation in your ``UserProvider`` class and call ``loadUserByParams`` inside

Comment: Just for info, refreshUser is called when the user is first pulled out of the session near the start of a request.  It give you the chance to see if any user database info has changed.  As long as you serialize the companyId then you are good.  Unless of course it's possible that some admin type might change a user's company. Then you might have problems.

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski where would I put loadUserByParams so that it is called?